# Почему вылетает ошибка?

Tags: java, android

Делаю такое `startactivity`

```
public static void share(Context context) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, context.getString(R.string.subject));
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, context.getString(R.string.message) +
            " " + context.getString(R.string.google_play_url));
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, context.getString(R.string.share_to)));
}
```

и вылетает с такой ошибкой

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.fittingroom.newtimezone, PID: 10326
>       android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   flag. Is this really what you want?
>       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:734)
>       at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:721)
>       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:345)
>       at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.UtilClass.share(UtilClass.java:428)
>       at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.activities.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:93)
>       at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder$5.onClick(DrawerBuilder.java:1716)
>       at com.mikepenz.materialdrawe

в строке

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, context.getString(R.string.share_to)));
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Пожалуйста, форматируйте логи так, чтобы их хотя бы читать можно было

Comment: Вы читали, что написано в стактрейсе?

Comment: @metalurgus да, но у меня стоит этот флаг... Или не там?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, у вас он стоит не у того интента. Сейчасс дополню ответ

Comment: А что вы хотели сделать-то? Вызвать активность не из активности?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В стактрейсе представлена исчерпывающая информация об ошибке:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

---

Переведу.

```
Вызов startActivity() вне контекста другого Activity требует флаг FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Вы это имели в виду?
```

Добавьте этот флаг в `Intent`, чтобы заработало.

---

Флаг-то есть, но не у того интента:

```
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, context.getString(R.string.share_to));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: да, но у меня стоит этот флаг... Или не там?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko не там. `createChooser` создаёт новый интент.